# Square Register API does not work. Is there a fix? [BUG]

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic2, square, square-connect

I have a problem with the Square Register API (docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/register-api-overview/). I want to use the Square Register API in my Ionic 2 iOS app.

**What I want to do**
I want to send a JSON with the data about a purchase to the Square Point of Sale (Square POS) App. The documentation of the Square Register API says that this should be easy to do. The app should open and the check out process of the Square POS App should be triggered with the data given by the JSON request from my app. After the check out is completed the Square POS App should redirect to my app to a success screen. In this case the Square POS app should redirect to "summitapp://page-success".

**The current status**
I have registered my own Square App (connect.squareup.com/apps/) and did the configuration which is needed for an iOS app (connect.squareup.com/apps/{appname}/register-api) [appname should be replaced with the square internal id which I replaced for security reasons]

I also edit the info.plist to match the data from the Square Register API with the data inside my app. This works fine.

I also build the code to do the things I describe @"What I want to do". You can see the code at the button of this stack overflow post. I managed to send a request from my app to the Square POS App. The Square POS App opens, but immediately after it opened it redirects back to my app. It than shows this error message: Apple Pay is not available when using "Point of Sale"

I have also made a video showing you the behavior of the app:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLpSmV1XXJ8

In this video the error message does not appear, because I already had opened it and did the process the second time. The error message just appears once when the Square POS app is opened the first time by my app.

This error message I get is strange, because Apple Pay is not activated for the german market and I don't use it. I tried many different solutions. I added different possible payment methods and tried everything, but the only error message I got was the desired "Apple Pay Error Message".

To give you a bit of background what stack the app is build on, here is a short description: I am using Ionic 2 with an iPad Air 2 or an iPhone 7 Plus as a test device. On both devices the same error message occurs. Both devices run on the latest iOS 10 version and have installed the latest Square POS App. I use Ionic 2 (Version 2.2.1) and Cordova (Version 6.5.0).

**What I tried**
I already tried all the tutorials at Square:

LINK => docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/register-api-ios

And some advice I got from Stack overflow articles

LINK => stackoverflow.com/questions/41188031/square-connect-api-navigate-back-to-app

I also tried to build a iOS with the SDK, but also that doesn't work.

To give you an overview how the Square Register API is integrated into my code here is a short code snippet.

The Code looks like this:

```
let params = {
      "amount_money": {
        "amount": 100,
        "currency_code": "USD"
      },
      "callback_url": "summitapp://page-success",
      "client_id": "sq0idp-xyz", // here goes the client_id
      "version": "1.2",
      "notes": "Shopping cart",
      "options": {
        "supported_tender_types": [
          "CREDIT_CARD"
        ],
        "auto_return": true
      }
};

let url = "square-commerce-v1://?data=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(params));
let browser = open(url, "_system", "location=true");
```

**My question / Where I need help**
I don't understand why the app allay redirects me to my app without any interaction happening on the Square POS App. Any help how to implement the Square POS App in an Ionic iOS app would be awesome.

I don't know if the bug is on the Square Register Apps side or on my side. If you know anything about this issue or if you can show me a working sample code of an iOS app which can open the Square POS App from another app and then do the check out based on the data provided by this app I would appreciate your comment on this stack overflow post.

I already check out the different tutorials and nothing worked. I hope to find someone who can help me fix that problem. I am decently going to write a blog post about this, because I think all people wanting to implement the Square Register API face the same problem.

Comment: Can you try to process a card payment in the Square point of sale app? If you can't (which you likely can not if you are in Germany) then you won't be able to process payments with a Register API integration. You should be receiving data back to your application after a failed app switch, have you checked that?

Comment: Square APIs are available only to developers in the United States and Canada.https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/faq-international-availability/

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I can accept payments if I just use the app itself. It doesn't have to be card payments. I would be happy if the Square POS app accepts any kind of payment which is triggered from my app. I don't get to the point where I can select the payment type. I just have just added "CREDIT_CARD" to the "supported_tender_types" as an example. Why I cannot use a German credit card? I didn't get that. Or why can't I use the normal "CASH" payment method?

I tried to get data back, when the app failed, but it didn't showed any data. Could you provide a solution to fetch the data?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ionic, but there are Android and iOS examples of the return data in the documentation. If you specify only cash, your application should work, just like you should be able to take cash payments with the Square point of sale app. Square cannot legally take card payments in germany at this time.

Comment: I tried also the iOS sample, but didn't got it to work either. At the current stage there is no difference between setting the supported_tender_types to "CREDIT_CARD" or "CASH". Both don't work and redirect immediately.  That Square is not allowed to take payments is okay. Thank you to clarify that.

Comment: for ios can show your code ? I am assuming you tried with native iOS code not with ionic